# Run docker inside pod without bind mounting host docker socket

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

We are running an AKS cluster which is not having docker installed. We are running an Azure DevOps self hosted agent as a Pod inside our AKS. But the blocker is we need that Pod to be able to build docker images as part of our CI/CD build. Is there any way to use docker inside pod without having the need to have docker on the k8s node on which that pod is scheduled? Please help…..

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of OCI-compliant images builders, such as:

- kaniko ( https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko )
- podman ( https://github.com/containers/podman )
- buildah ( https://github.com/containers/buildah )
- img from genuinetools ( https://github.com/genuinetools/img )
- buildkit ( https://github.com/moby/buildkit )
- umoci ( https://github.com/opencontainers/umoci )

Starting from scratch, you could checkout samples from the Tekton Hub. Even if you do not mean to run Tekton: you could re-use some of their sample Tasks building your own containers.

For Docker-In-Docker (DIND) builds, podman may not be the best pick (meant as a drop-in replacement for Docker runtime on end-user workstations). Sticking to RedHat ecosystem: buildah would be recommended. With portability in mind (arm/arm64 builds on RPI), I would usually go with Kaniko.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, can you please also tell how can I run containers too? as the solution you suggested seems to work perfect for building images, but what if we wanted to run containers too without docker daemon?

Comment: All those tools ship with container images, that can run in Kubernetes. None of them requires access to an existing Docker runtime (note for buildkit: there's a daemonless option to do this), They're self-sufficient. Check out Tekton Hub sample Tasks for sample containers definitions, that could be translated into Deployments, Jobs, ...

Comment: here's a container, wrapped into a Tekton Task, using Kaniko: https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/blob/main/task/kaniko/0.5/kaniko.yaml#L49-L62 . Outside of Tekton, you'ld have to add some initContainer to clone your source repository and share this with the kaniko container, maybe mounting some secret authenticating with your registry, ...